# Powershell Script to run exe file with parameters

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, exe

I need script to run exe file with parameters.
That's what I wrote, if there's a better way to do it?

```js
$Command = "\\Networkpath\Restart.exe"
$Parms = "/t:21600 /m:360 /r /f"
$Prms = $Parms.Split(" ")
& "$Command" $Prms
```

thanks

Comment: I would use `Start-Process` but your example works as well.

Comment: You don't need `"` around `$Command`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart `"$($Command.ToString())"` :P

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a couple options when running an external executable.

---

## [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

```
$command = '\\netpath\restart.exe'
$params = '/t:21600', '/m:360', '/r', '/f'
& $command @params
```

This method will essentially join your array as arguments to the executable.  This allows your list of arguments to be cleaner and can be re-written as:

```
$params = @(
    '/t:21600'
    '/m:360'
    '/r'
    '/f'
)
```

This is usually my favorite way to address the problem.

---

## Call the executable with arguments at once

You don't necessarily need to have variables or even the [call operator (`&`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1) if you don't have spaces in arguments, path, etc.

```
\\netpath\restart.exe /t:21600 /m:360 /r /f
```

---

### [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1)

This is my second go-to because it gives me more control over the eventual process.  Sometimes executables spawn sub-processes and your call operator won't wait for the process to end before moving on in your script.  This method gives you control over that.

```
$startParams = @{
    FilePath     = '\\netpath\restart.exe'
    ArgumentList = '/t:21600', '/m:360', '/r', '/f'
    Wait         = $true
    PassThru     = $true
}
$proc = Start-Process @startParams
$proc.ExitCode
```

---

### [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.5.2)

Last of the methods I know, using the `Process` .NET class directly.  I use this method if I need even more control of the process, such as collecting its output:

```
try {
    $proc = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start([System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]@{
        FileName               = "\\netshare\restart.exe"
        Arguments              = '/t:21600 /m:360 /r /f'
        CreateNoWindow         = $true
        UseShellExecute        = $false
        RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    })
    $output = $proc.StandardOutput
    $output.ReadToEnd()
} finally {
    if ($null -ne $proc) {
        $proc.Dispose()
    }
    if ($null -ne $output) {
        $output.Dispose()
    }
}
```